# Extract number or text from One row data

Tags: excel-formula

I need solution fro this:

/Women/Dresses/Short-sleeved-Peplum-Dress/p/8503311?utm_extID=Dec10

I need to extract data between /p/ and ? i,e 8503311
total len of this line is 67 but if differs not fixed

I tried by using find function not able get solution

Answer (score 1):

if it's always after `p/` and the length of number is fixed (in your example = 7), this should work:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("p/",A1)+2,7)
```

This is assuming data in `A1`.

Comment: If it has a dynamic length, instead of 7 in the formula you can do a search formula for the ? and subtract the result of the other search formula for p/.

Answer (score 0):

should be like:

```
import re
x = '/Women/Dresses/Short-sleeved-Peplum-Dress/p/8503311?utm_extID=Dec10' 
re.search('(?<=/p/)\d+',x).group()
```

Comment: looks like you're responding in Python to an Excel question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data string is in A1, this should return everything between, but not including, the first instance of `/p/` and the first `?` thereafter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("/p/",A1)+3,FIND("?",MID(A1,FIND("/p/",A1)+4,LEN(A1))))
```